# How to access the dictionary from a list of dictionaries using one key/value pair of the dictionary that I want to fetch

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, which all have the same keys. I have a specific value of one key and want to access/print the dictionary, which contains this specific value. I couldn't think of any way, other than looping around the whole list, checking the corresponding value of the key and printing it out using if statement, that is if the given value matched the key.

```
for enrollment in enrollments:
    if enrollment['account_key'] == a:
        print(enrollment)
    else:
        continue
```

This does not really seem the most efficient way to handle the task. What would be a better solution?

Comment: Are you planning to do this multiple times? Or just one time? Please a some sample data

Comment: You're right in that that's not the most efficient way to handle the task, but that has more to do with the fact that your data structure is not conducive to this type of operation. The correct way to perform this task would be to use a more appropriate data structure that allows for this type of lookup, like a dictionary of dictionaries, assuming your `account_key` values are all unique.

Comment: You don’t need the else/continue

Comment: Given your data structure, there is no alternative.  How could there be?  You can't possibly know where that value lives without checking them all.  If you know there's exactly one, you can always `break` after the `print` to stop looking further.

Comment: If the alternative is `print(“\n”.join([v for v in enrollments if v.get(‘account_key’)==‘a’]))` I’d rather use the three-line for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

1- Use the loop like you do here, although this could be written simpler without the continue.

```
for enrollment in enrollments:
    if enrollment['account_key'] == a:
        print(enrollment)
```

2- Use a generator expression and `next`

```
enrollment = next(e for e in enrollments if e['account_key'] == a)
print(enrollment)
```

3- Convert the list of dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries. This is a good option if you have to do this operation many times and there is only one value for each `account_key`

```
accounts = {
    enrollment['account_key']: enrollment
    for enrollment in enrollments
}
print(accounts[a])
```

4- Same as above, but if there are multiple values for the same key, you can use a dict of lists of dicts.

```
accounts = defaultdict(list)
for enrollment in enrollments:
    accounts[enrollment['account_key']].append(enrollment)

for enrollment in accounts[a]:
    print(enrollment)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension (iterator) to get the subset of dictionaries that match your criteria.  In any case this will be a sequential search process.

```
enrolments = [ {'account_key':1, 'other':99},
               {'account_key':2, 'other':98},
               {'account_key':1, 'other':97},
               {'account_key':1, 'other':96},
               {'account_key':3, 'other':95} ]

a = 1
found = (d for d in enrolments if d['account_key']==a)
print(*found,sep="\n")

{'account_key': 1, 'other': 99}
{'account_key': 1, 'other': 97}
{'account_key': 1, 'other': 96}
```